# How can I find the hostname and port in the settings django for the full path of the image to be displayed in the email?

Tags: python, django, static

So I am trying to give the absolute path for the static folder. Can you point what I am doing wrong?

My template looks like 
`<img src="{{ALLOWED_HOSTS}}{% static 'assets/img/logo-ST.png' %}" alt="logo" border="0" width="102">`

And in the Settings

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', str)`

I know I'm doing something wring with the hostname and port, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the url, not the file path, so just use:

```
<img src="{% static "assets/img/logo-ST.png" %}" ...>
```

in your template, and

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://example.com/'
```

in `settings.py`.
(remember to run `python manage.py collectstatic`)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `BASE_URL` constant to your settings file

```
# settings.py

BASE_URL = env.str('BASE_URL')
```

Create a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
# templatetags/__init__.py
# templatetags/settings_tag.py

from django import template
from django.conf import settings as django_settings

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def settings():
    return django_settings
```

Your email template

```
{% load settings_tag %}

<img src="{% settings.BASE_URL %}{% static 'assets/img/logo-ST.png' %}" alt="logo" border="0" width="102">
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I want the email for the reset password so I do not have a separate view for it, it's just the html template

Comment: Updated answer to use a template tag instead. This way you don't need access to the view.